# dpkg broken while upgrading Debian Etch to Lenny

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

Good day!

While trying to recover a box to lenny it seems I've broken things. It upgrades `libc` and `glib` after that dpkg seems to be broken.

I can run `apt-get`, but it gets segmentation fault from dpkg:

```
# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 316 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B of archives.
After unpacking 0B of additional disk space will be used.
/bin/sh: line 1:  4606 Segmentation fault      /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg received a segmentation fault.
```

I can login via SSH but even ls is not working:

```
# ls
Segmentation fault
```

Is there anything I can do remotelly via SSH?

```
    # ldd /bin/ls
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xb7fc8000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib/libacl.so.1 (0xb7fc2000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0xb7fac000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7e51000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7e3f000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7fd8000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/libattr.so.1 (0xb7e3b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb7e37000)
    libsepol.so.1 => /lib/libsepol.so.1 (0xb7df6000)
```

*It seems I've temporary fixed it with*:

```
 # touch /etc/ld.so.nohwcap
```

From here: http://saintaardvarkthecarpeted.com/blog/archive/2005/08/_etc_ld_so_nohwcap.html

Comment: Can you execute other commands like `less` to view log files?

Comment: Yes, `less`, `tail` work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should enable core file dumping by `ulimit -c unlimited` and run the failing program to get a coredump then. If you are lucky and `gdb` is installed and not segfaulting, you can analyze a coredump in place by `gdb -c core.pid`. It will show you at least an address of failing instruction so you will able to guess the failing lib from that address. If `gdb` is not installed, try to `scp` the coredump to some other host. Next step is probably to replace the failing lib by some other version from some other host by `scp`.

Comment: It seems I've fixed it temporary with `touch /etc/ld.so.nohwcap`

Comment: I am still getting an error: **/bin/sh: 1: /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package debconf (--configure):**